# How to give proper syntax in webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm able to automate using webdriver but there are few syntax like

`driver.manage().setscriptTimeout(100, Seconds);`

(copied from other site). How to know that after `manage()`, `setscriptTimeout()` follows?

That means how to predict correct methods for timeouts or something like that in `webdriver`.

Copy paste can be done, but few companies doesn't prefer copy paste job, they need genuine testers who can put the syntax in brain. Please let me know how to master syntax.

Comment: Get automating. Automate everything you could get your hands on. Use Stackoverflow, google wherever neeeded. You will get there soon.

Comment: The same way everyone else does, just look at the docs and get used to the API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644868/webdriver-selenium-2-api-documentation ...Selenium is not special in that regard. MSDN, for instance, is an invaluable source for C# developers.

Comment: use the Selenium WEbdriver Docs to get more info on what functions/classess are available and what they do... Link 1: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/index.jsp
Link 2: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using? An IDE such as IntelliJ (Java), Rubymine(Ruby), Visual STudio(C#), etc. will give you auto complete (also known as Intellisense)

Comment: I'm using Java language

Comment: Then using an IDE like Intellij will provide intellisense and provide all possible methods for the driver and element